# Why is my scroll function always targeting the same position?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am doing an image slider in ReactJs which consists on the same amount of dots (buttons) than the amount of images cards. The issue is that i was able to make a scroll function but it is working just for the first time i click and it targets always the same position which is the inbetween of the first 2 cards.

e.g is i click in the fourth dot instead of sliding into the fourth card it slide to the middle between the first one and the second one.

This is my component Work.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './Work.css'
import Cta from '../atoms/Cta'
import Headphone from '../assets/images/headphones3.png'
import Calendar from '../assets/images/calendar.png'
import DevConnector from '../assets/images/dev.png'
import Bulls from '../assets/images/bulls2.png'
import Expenses from '../assets/images/reactExpenses.png'
import SixFlags from '../assets/images/sixflags.png'
import useDots from '../hooks/useDots';


const images = [Calendar, Headphone, SixFlags, DevConnector, Bulls, Expenses];

const Work = () => {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useDots(images.length);
    const [showDots, setShowDots] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
          setShowDots(window.innerWidth <= 810);
        }
    
        handleResize();
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
      }, []);

    function handleDotClick(index) {
        console.log("Clicked dot with index:", index);
      
        setActiveIndex(index);
      
        const targetCard = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${index}"]`);
        console.log("Target card:", targetCard);

        if (targetCard) {
          const magicWall = document.querySelector('#home-magicwall ul');
          const magicWallRect = magicWall.getBoundingClientRect();
          const magicWallOffsetLeft = magicWallRect.left + window.scrollX;
          console.log("Magic wall:", magicWall);
          console.log("Target card offsetLeft:", targetCard.offsetLeft);
          console.log("Magic wall offsetLeft:", magicWall.offsetLeft);
      
          magicWall.scroll({
            left: targetCard.offsetLeft - magicWallOffsetLeft,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }

      }
  
    

    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <section id="work">
          <div id="header">
            <h2>My Work</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="text-zone-2">
            <div>
              <p>
                A small gallery of recent projects chosen by me. I've done them all together with amazing people from
                companies around the globe. It's only a drop in the ocean compared to the entire list. Interested to see
                some more? Visit my work page.
                <br />
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-container">
              <Cta className="btn" link="https://github.com/mateoghidini1998" content="See More" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="fake-big-2">Work</div>
        </section>
        {showDots && (
          <div className="dots">
            {images.map((image, index) => (
              <button
                key={index}
                className={`dot ${index === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}`}
                onClick={() => handleDotClick(index)}
              ></button>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
        <div id="home-magicwall" className="fake-magicwall">
          <ul>
            {images.map((image, index) => (
              <li key={index} className={`magic-wall_item ${index === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                <img src={image} alt="image" />
                <div className="hover-content"></div>
                <a href="/" className="colorbox" data-id={index}></a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};

export default Work;
```

This is my custom hook useDots.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function useDots(images) {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  return [activeIndex, setActiveIndex];
}

export default useDots;
```

And this is part of my css:

```
.fake-magicwall {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .fake-magicwall ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .fake-magicwall ul li {
    width: 50%;
    height: 550px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: list-item;
  }
  
  .fake-magicwall ul li:hover .magic-wall_item {
    transform: scale(1.14);
  }
  
  .magic-wall_item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  }
  
  .fake-magicwall img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    .fake-magicwall ul {
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-x: auto;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    #home-magicwall {
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: auto;
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .fake-magicwall ul li {
      width: 100%;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
  
    .dot {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }
```

The issue might be on how i´m calculating `magicWallOffsetLeft` or maybe some css issues with some widths but i cant figure what.

Comment: Do you want a "scroll" event or a "resize" event? But in any case, place the ` function handleResize() {    setShowDots(window.innerWidth <= 810);   }` outside the `useEffect`

Comment: To make it easier to debug, you should keep the elements in state and address them from state. As it is now, you are working around React to directly grab elements from the DOM; something that should only be done by exception and preferably by using useRef() or another React friendly method. Because mixing DOM and React is known to end up in weird behavior like this.